# str.length() not working as i think it should

Tags: android, string

When I enter "AA" into my  2 TextViews it never moves to my other acitivty when "AA".length() should be 2 making it switch to my other activity but it never does. I then checked to see what its printing out and it printing 98 and 94 as the 2 lengths of the strings when it should be 2 2 any suggestions?

```
public class DataEntry extends Activity {
String parent1 = "";
String parent2 = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_entry);
    Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFirstParent);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtParent2);
            String str = tv.toString().trim();
            String str2 = tv1.toString().trim();
            parent1 = str;
            parent2 = str2;
            if(str.length()==2 && str2.length()==2){
                Intent otherIntent = new Intent(DataEntry.this, MonoHybrid.class);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent1",parent1);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent2",parent2);
                startActivity(otherIntent);
            }
            else if(str.length()==4 && str2.length()==4){
                Intent otherIntent = new Intent(DataEntry.this, DiHybrid.class);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent1",parent1);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent2",parent2);
                startActivity(otherIntent);
            }
            else if(str.length()==6 && str2.length()==6){
                Intent otherIntent = new Intent(DataEntry.this, TriHybrid.class);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent1",parent1);
                otherIntent.putExtra("parent2",parent2);
                startActivity(otherIntent);
            }
            else
                tv.setText(str.length() +" "+ str2.length());
                tv1.setText(str.length() + " " + str2.length());
                //tv.setText("Error please enter a MonoHybrid \"AA\" DiHybrid \"AABB\" or TriHybrid \"AABBCC\"");
                //tv1.setText("Error please enter a MonoHybrid \"AA\" DiHybrid \"AABB\" or TriHybrid \"AABBCC\"");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String str = tv.getText().toString().trim();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're getting the text from the TextView properly.

Try

```
String str = tv.getText().toString();
String str2 = tv1.getText().toString();
```

TextView.toString() returns a human-readable description of the object, not the actual text that was entered (from [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)).